# Oracle Reports builder 12C - FunctionBODY Encountered symbol '"' when expecting one of the following :=.@%;

Tags: oracle12c, reportbuilder, oraclereports

I am not sure whether this is right forum to ask. But I am facing very weird issue with Oracle reports builder 12c version. We have an Oracle application for which Oracle forms (fmb) and reports (RDF) where created in Oracle 6i version few years back. We migrated them to 12C recently.

I am inserting two SQL blocks and few frames, fields in my RDF. Everything is going fine, rdf compiling without any issues in windows. But when I reopen the file, The code in function body and sometimes SQL statements of newly created blocks/fields are showing junk values like below. Attached snap.

And throwing error : Error 103 Encountered symbol '"' when expecting one of the following :=.@%;

I am removing the corresponding field, inserting again and adding just an IF CONDITION code in FORMATTRIGGER function body. no issues with the logic.

What is causing such issues? How to fix this. Is this issue with software or any settings to be changed?[oracle12Cjunk](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h4a37.png) This is not occurring in any other old SQL blocks or program units.

I tried typing the code, copy pasting from wordpad..but still same issue.

```
IF :Q1_CODE1  = 'DH' THEN
  return (TRUE);
  ELSE
    RETURN(FALSE);
  END IF;
```

Comment: No idea, but - try to **a)** delete those objects and create them again; **b)** save report as a .JSP file, exit Reports, run it again, open the .JSP file and see what happens (whether you got garbage again or not); **c)** if report isn't too complex, rewrite it from scratch

Comment: Thanks much for your comments! I tried a) but not working. Couldnt try C) as it is complex report indeed. Will try b) once.

Comment: You're welcome. Good luck!